# Laravel-5.5 Call to member function products on Null error (Many to Many Relationships)

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.5, laravel-seeding

Hi I created database seeder as "CartSeeder" but I cant start seeding, it gives me that error. I checked my codes several times, but it seems fine for me.

I have three table, carts, products and pivot table. I have their models. You can see the informations about them below.

CartSeeder;

```
$cart = Cart::where('user_id',\Auth::id())->first();
$products = Product::inRandomOrder()->take(5)->get();
$cart->products()->sync($products,false);
```

Cart Model;

```
public function products(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product','cart_product','cart_id','product_id');
    }
```

Product Model;

```
public function carts(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Cart','cart_product','product_id','cart_id');
    }
```

Where do I mistake in here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means you do not have any carts where `user_id` equals to authenticated user's ID. This is because you run seeder using console command and not web request.

Comment: it means we cannot see logged users without http request ?

Comment: @cervantes yes, you can't do that. If you're running the command dynamically, you could pass `auth()->id()` as a seeder parameter or something.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the error, make sure `$cart` variable is not null.

Add:

```
dd($cart);
```

to make sure it's not null

Also in real app it's often better to use `firstOrFail` like so:

```
$cart = Cart::where('user_id',\Auth::id())->firstOrFail();
```

in some cases. This will guarantee that app will stop if there is no cart for this user.

Comment: Have you run this when you are seeding? Normally when you are seeding you don't have any logged user.

Comment: Man you was right, $cart returns null. But why ? I logged before seeding

Comment: When you run command via console, it doesn't matter you have logged in using website. If you want to authenticate user, add in seeding `auth()->loginUsingId(2);` to login user with id 2

Comment: Have you run it before line `$cart = Cart::where('user_id',\Auth::id())->first();` ?

Comment: I tried again and it works, I made a shameful mistake, now I realized :)